# How do I iterate over a string array in C and C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c

I found sample code that iterates over a C style string array inside a main function, the code works fine and looks like this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (TCHAR **iList = argv; *iList != NULL; ++iList)
    {
        wcout << *iList << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

There is a part which I don't understand:

```
*iList != NULL
```

Maybe somebody can explain to me this part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-style strings are also called null-terminated strings. That just means that you have the characters of the actual string laid out together in memory, and then after all of those characters, you have the null character. So when you want to iterate over all the characters in a C-style string, you just need to start at the beginning and keep going until you reach a null character.

In this particular example, however, you're dealing with an *array of strings*, not just a single string. What this means is that `argv` actually points to a location in memory which is the beginning of a list of pointers. Each pointer in that list then points to a C-style string. At the end of this array of pointers, you have a `NULL` pointer, so once you reach that, you've iterated over all the strings in `argv`.

Let's look at it line-by-line:

```
for (TCHAR **iList = argv; *iList != NULL; ++iList)
```

OK, that's too complicated. Let's just look at the first expression first:

```
TCHAR **iList = argv;
```

This declares a variable `iList` which is of type `TCHAR**`. That means it is a pointer to a pointer to a `TCHAR`. Its value points to the location of a pointer, and that pointer then points to the location of the beginning of a C-style string.

```
*iList != NULL;
```

This takes the thing pointed to by `iList` and sees if it is a `NULL` pointer. Remember that `iList` points to pointers, so the goal is to keep examining pointers pointed to by `iList` until you find one that actually doesn't point to anything (that's what `NULL` means), and stop.

```
++iList
```

This just means that, every time you execute the body of the `for` loop, you add 1 to the value of `iList`. Since `iList` is a pointer to pointers, we're telling `iList` to point to the pointer right after the one it was previously pointing to.

And finally:

```
wcout << *iList << endl;
```

This means to take whatever is pointed to by `iList` (a pointer, because `iList` points to pointers) and insert it into `wcout`, followed by a newline character. The insertion operator in this case is smart: since the thing pointed to by `iList` is a pointer to characters, it knows to interpret it as a C-style string, and so follows the characters pointed to by that pointer that `iList` points to (yay, confusion) until it finds a null character, and prints all those characters to the screen. The `endl` acts as both a newline and a signal to flush the `wcout` buffer (print it directly to the screen instead of just keeping it in memory).

Comment: `*iList != 0` works because std::§3.6.1-2 "The value of argv[argc] shall be 0."

Answer (score 1):

To break it down to simplest form;
Think of a 2-D array,

> [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [0,3] [0,4] [0,5]
>
> [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] [1,5]
>
> [2,0] [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] [2,4] [2,5]
>
> [3,0] [3,1] [3,2] [3,3] [3,4] [3,5]
>
> [4,0] [4,1] [4,2] [4,3] [4,4] [4,5]
>
> [5,0] [5,1] [5,2] [5,3] [5,4] [5,5]
>
> NULL

Each element is a TCHAR element representing a single character, Each row is a string(an array of characters is a string), with the last element begin '\0'(NULL terminator)

`**ilist = argv` means ilist points to the first element of matrix i.e. [0,0]

`*ilist` represents the complete row, so printing it using cout will print out a string that is contained int that row

`++ilist` increments the pointer to first element of next row(so incrementing it one time will make ilist to point at [1,0])

`ilist != NULL` checks whether we have reached the end of the matrix, so the loop executes until the end of matrix has not been reached, the last row(the one after 5th row, contains NULL, thus conveying the end of array)

(The actually array representation in memory is not the same as above, it is almost similar, the number of element in a row vary according to the string length, For example suppose the arguments are : "This is a string", it can be represented as:

```
[0]->[T] [h] [i] [s] [\0]  
[1]->[i] [s] [\0]  
[2]->[a] [\0]
[3]->[s] [t] [r] [i] [n] [g] [\0]
[4]->NULL
```

Remember `'\0'` is null terminator, it is used to tell that this is the end of the string)